# Youppi! Youppie! Youpi!

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, oral, québec, réforme-orthographique-1991

Le terme existe dans la langue québécoise depuis au moins une cinquantaine d’années, quoique son entrée dans le Robert, sous la forme *youpi*, soit plus récente (je n’ai pas la date exacte de son entrée, mais il n’y était pas, du moins, en 1984).

L’équipe de baseball de Montréal a adopté sa mascotte *Youppi!* en 1979. D’aussi loin que je me rappelle, le nom de cette mascotte se prononce [jup.pi], avec un arrêt marqué entre les deux P, les lèvres demeurant fermées, mais le I n’étant énoncé qu’après une aspiration formant l’énonciation du second P.

Le cri de joie, pour moi et bien d’autres, s’énonce de la même manière, et même chez ceux pour qui le mot est prononcé [jupi], la variante à deux P ne provoque jamais aucune remarque, sourire ou autre.

Récemment, j’ai cependant remarqué que dans la foulée des rectifications orthographiques de 1991, l’Office québécois de la langue française a [pris position](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4736) pour privilégier la forme à un seul P aux deux formes jusqu’alors en coexistence du terme, soient *youppi* et *youppie*, arguant qu’en cas de mots ayant plus d’une graphie *traditionnelle*...

> on préférera tout simplement la forme qui est la plus simple, la plus française, la moins ambiguë ou la plus régulière.

Je ne saurais dire si les graphies traditionnelles des mots présentés sur la page en lien sont encore acceptées, puisqu’ils semblent *tomber à côté* des règles des rectifications de 1991, mais d’une manière ou d’une autre, il me semble que l’on nuit au mot en lui retirant l’un de ses P, puisque le double P permettrait les deux prononciations citées ci-dessus, ce que ne permet pas le simple P.

---

- La prononciation à deux P est-elle encore vivante de nos jours ?
- Si oui, sa présence dans la langue orale québécoise est-elle en régression, ou se maintient-elle en dépit des nouvelles règles orthographiques ?

---

M’est revenu à la mémoire l’exemple parfait pour illustrer les deux prononciations : l’humoriste québécois François Perusse a fait une parodie dans le style d’Ozzy Osbourne, intitulée *« Brouillard sur le cimetière »*, où le dernier couplet indique : *« Ma blonde sort avec Satan youppi youppi ! »*, les deux derniers mots étant prononcés [ju.pi.jup.piː]. On l’entend, juste après la marque des 30 secondes, sur ce [montage vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zvr5ZC5n6-o&t=34s).

Answer (score 2):

Je consulte plusieurs dictionnaires postérieurs à 1995. Tous donnent youpi. Une autre variante est youpie.

La première attestation se trouve dans un vaudeville, en 1842, sous la forme ayant un seul *p*. (source: livio-android apk hors ligne). La définition du dictionnaire est :

> De l'anglais whoppee ou yippee. Attesté dans un vaudeville, en 1842,
>   sous la forme de ouap, ouap, youp, youp qui correspond au refrain
>   anglais whoppee, yippee, yipee (yay).

C'est bizarre quand même cette disparition du *p*, car il me semble que yuppie doit aussi s'écrire avec un seul *p* d'après la règle de simplification...

Comment: Les règles de simplification demandent en effet que la consonne doublée disparaisse si elle n'apporte rien. Le fait est que je perçois une utilité au double P de ce cas particulier, puisque la prononciation habituelle au Québec (ou au moins l'une des prononciations habituelles) en fait usage. Il existe de nombreux cas aussi de double M, systématiquement prononcés par les contemporains de mes grands-parents (aujourd'hui pour la plupart décédés), un peu moins par les générations suivantes, mais néanmoins encore présents à ce jour. À ma connaissance, aucune rectification dans ces cas.

Comment: Merci pour la variante: mon Robert 2010 ne la donne pas, mais elle semble logique. Je serais intéressé par l'attestation de 1842. Pourriez-vous me donner plus de détails?

Comment: Ouap, youp, youp qui correspond au refrain anglais whoppee, yippee, yippee. Source dictionnaire Livio pour Android. Vous pouvez le télécharger ici https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.fr_FR&hl=fr

Comment: Il convient de surligner que ce dictionnaire est gratuit, peut s'emploie hors-ligne et n'inclut pas d'annonces. En plus, il donne traductions en, parmi d'autres, anglais et allemand. Moi j'ai installé les dictionnaires livio pour l'anglais, l'allemand et le français. De cette façon on possède un référencement croisé invaluable:-)!

Comment: Il ne me manque qu'un appareil Android. C'est un ennui majeur, par contre... :( Pourriez-vous citer l'attestation?

Comment: J'ai mentionné ci-dessous. Je la répète : "...Ouap, youp, youp qui correspond au refrain anglais whoppee, yippee, yippee." Source dictionnaire Livio

Comment: Pardonnez-moi, je n'avais pas fait le lien. C'est tiré de quel vaudeville?

Comment: Pas de souci:-)! Je viens de rajouter la complète citation. Malheureusement il ne donne pas d'autre information concernant ledit vaudeville.

Comment: Le dictionnaire donne une autre citation plus recente mais vieille quand même. **Youpi**, on va pouvoir sortir dehors ! (Claude Jasmin, La Petite Patrie, 1972, p. 76.).

Comment: Je ne sais pas si vous pouvez poser une question directement à l'auteur:-)! http://www.claudejasmin.com/wordpress/faq/

Comment: Je viens de trouver que livio existe pour Windows et Mac (pour Linux je n'ai aucune idée:-)!). Essayez ici si vous voulez https://softstribe.com/app/pc/download-install-livio-pack-lang-fr-fr-windows-mac-os

Comment: Ce commentaire pour vous dire que j'ai bien écrit à M. Jasmin. J'en ai même eu une réponse! Bien laconique, il est vrai, aussi n'avais-je pas cru bon de la mentionner ici. Mais pourquoi pas, finalement. Ça donnera bien une idée de l'importance de cette interrogation primordiale. Voici donc en primeur la réponse que je reçus de M. Jasmin: «AUCUNE IDÉE... regrets!» ... voilà voilà...